# Multiplicity relation between highest weight modules, Demazure modules, and crystals

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, kac-moody-algebras, crystals

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a symmetrizable Kac--Moody algebra, and let $\lambda$ be an associated dominant integral weight. Then two different objects we can relate to this data is $V(\lambda)$, the irreducible highest weight representation, and $B(\lambda)$, the irreducible highest weight crystal. Fix $e_i, f_i \in \mathfrak{g}$ to be simple positive/negative root generators, respectively; similarly, fix $\tilde{e_i}, \tilde{f_i}$ to be the simple crystal operators.

The two facts that I would like to recall first deal with tensor product decompositions in their respective settings. Namely, first consider $V(\lambda) \otimes V(\mu)$. Then a classical result of Kostant (at least when $\mathfrak{g}$ is a finite-dimensional, semisimple Lie algebra) says that $V(\nu)$ appears as an irreducible component of the tensor product with multiplicity
$$
m_{\lambda, \mu}^\nu :=\text{dim}\{v \in V(\mu)_{\nu-\lambda}: e_i^{\lambda(\alpha_i^\vee)+1}.v=0 \ \forall \ \text{simple roots }\alpha_i \}.
$$

Similarly, we have that the crystal $B(\nu)$ appears in the tensor product of crystals $B(\lambda) \otimes B(\mu)$ with multiplicity
$$
c_{\lambda, \mu}^\nu:=|\{b \in B(\mu): wt(b)=\nu-\lambda,\  \tilde{e_i}^{\lambda(\alpha_i^\vee)+1}.b=0 \ \forall \ i\}|;
$$

I know of this result in the combinatorial setting, via Littelmann's path model. In fact, since in that setting the path model gives an alternative way to find multiplicities in the tensor product of representations, we have that $m_{\lambda, \mu}^\nu = c_{\lambda, \mu}^\nu$.

Now, fix a Weyl group element $w \in W$, and consider the Demazure module $V_w(\lambda)$, and Demazure crystal $B_w(\lambda)$. We take, as a definition, the two following integers
$$
m_{\lambda, \mu, w}^\nu:= \text{dim}\{v \in V_w(\mu)_{\nu-\lambda}: e_i^{\lambda(\alpha_i^\vee)+1}.v=0 \ \forall \ i \},
$$

$$
c_{\lambda, \mu, w}^\nu:= |\{b \in B_w(\mu): wt(b)=\nu-\lambda,\  \tilde{e_i}^{\lambda(\alpha_i^\vee)+1}.b=0 \ \forall \ i\}|.  
$$

> Question: Is $m_{\lambda, \mu, w}^\nu = c_{\lambda, \mu, w}^\nu$?

I believe that the correct way to approach this question would be through the crystal basis of representations in the *quantum groups* setting; however, I don't have much exposure to that topic. For the case of highest weight modules and highest weight crystals, I might expect to see a justification of $m_{\lambda, \mu}^\nu = c_{\lambda, \mu}^\nu$ along the lines of a "classical limit" statement; similarly, I could believe a similar justification for $m_{\lambda, \mu, w}^\nu = c_{\lambda, \mu, w}^\nu$, since the crystal base of the quantum Demazure module is the intersection of the module with the crystal base of the quantum highest weight module. But again, I am not confident in my knowledge of quantum groups to make such a "classical limit" (or otherwise) statement precise.